# malloc function memory management

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

`malloc()` function forms a single block of memory (say 20 bytes typecasted to `int`), so how it can be used as an array of `int` blocks like as `calloc()` function? Shouldn't it be used to store just one `int` value in whole 20 bytes (20*8 bits)?

Answer (score 6):

> *(say 20 bytes typecasted to int)*

No, the returned memory is given as a pointer to `void`, an incomplete type.

We assign the returned pointer to a variable of pointer to some type, and we can use that variable to access the memory.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3, *Memory management functions*

> [....] The
>   pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to
>   a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used
>   to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space
>   is explicitly deallocated). [...] The pointer returned points to the start (lowest byte address) of the
>   allocated space. [....]

Since the allocated memory is contiguous, pointer arithmetic works, just as in case of arrays, since in arrays also, elements are placed in contiguous memory.

One point to clarify, [**a pointer is not an array.**](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/)

Comment: like in 16 bit architecture we use 2 bytes(16 bit) to represent an integer value in form of 0s and 1s and in 32 bit architecture we use 4 bytes(32 bits) to represent the same integer value. That means one block of int type of whatever memory contains one int only. Shouldn't this apply to malloc as well ,as being one large block of memory.

Comment: @VIbhor Yes, if you allocate memory worth `sizeof` one `int`, you'll get either 2 bytes or 4 bytes, depending on your environment. However, if you're asking for 20 bytes, malloc will return a memory of 20 bytes, it has no knowledge about the future use of that memory.

Comment: @VIbhor Are you by any chance confusing bits and bytes here?

Comment: I am just confused on how one single int variable block formed by malloc can store multiple int values which we used to store using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @VIbhor It’s not a single `int` variable, it’s a single block of *multiple* `int` variables.

Comment: @VIbhor `one single int variable block`- no, not like that. As I mentioned earlier, the memory returned by malloc is not based on any type, it's just a memory, with a defined size, suitable aligned to be assigned to a pointer of any other type - that's it.

Comment: If it is not a single variable but contains multiple blocks then how it is different from calloc As in calloc mutiple blocks are created as an array ,so we store multiple values but in malloc one block is created which should store only one value/ one sequence of 0s and 1s. no?

Comment: @VIbhor It does not initialize the memory. It's all in the man page.

Comment: It does not contain multiple blocks. `malloc()` returns a pointer to a single section of dynamically allocated memory of a specified size. If that "specified size" is 20 times the size of an `int`, then that memory can be used to store 20 distinct values of type `int` - by casting the `void` pointer returned by `malloc()` to an `int *`, and treating it as if it is an array. `calloc(num, size)` also returns a single section of size `num*size`, which can be used to store `num` values of size `size` (and the contents of the memory is initialised as if it is an array of `num` zeros).

Comment: @VIbhor: to put it differently, it's not _one (single-int) variable block_, but _one single (int-variable-block)_, meaning a single block which contains int variables.

Answer (score 1):

There's an abstract concept in C formally known as *effective type*, meaning the actual type of the data stored in memory. This is something the compiler keeps track of internally.

Most objects in C have such an effective type at the point when the variable is declared, for example if we type `int a;` then the effective type of what's stored in `a` is `int`.

Meaning it is legal to do evil things like this:

```
int a;
double* d = (double*)&a;
*(int*)d = 1;
```

This works because the effective type of the actual memory remains an `int`, even though we pointed at it with a wildly incompatible type. As long as we access it with the same type as the effective type, all is well. If we access the data using the wrong type, very bad things will happen, such as program crashes or dormant bugs.

But when we call `malloc` family of functions, we only tell them to reserve `n` number of bytes, with no type specified. This memory is guaranteed to be allocated in adjacent memory cells, but nothing else. The only difference between `malloc` and `calloc` is that the latter sets all values in this raw memory to zero. Neither function knows anything about types or arrays.

The returned chunk of raw memory has no effective type. Not until the point when we access it, then it gets the effective type which corresponds to the type used for the access.

So just as in the previous example, it doesn't matter which type of pointer we set to point at the data. It doesn't matter if we write `int* i = malloc(n);` or `bananas_t* b = malloc(n);`, because the pointed-at memory does not yet have a type. It does not get one until at the point where we access it for the first time.

Comment: As a difference between `malloc` and `calloc`, `calloc` implementations tend to check for overflow. Also, your example may cause UB according to §6.3.2.3 ¶7. Otherwise, a great answer.

Comment: @ninjalj The UB in §7 is extremely theoretical. There are no systems with pointers of different alignment requirements. Different pointer sizes, sure, but a pointer that when converted to a larger pointer type gets misaligned? I'm fairly sure that such systems have never existed and will never exist. I don't even know why this part is in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about memory returned from `malloc` compared to memory returned from `calloc`, other that the fact that the bytes of the memory block returned by `calloc` are initialized to 0.  Memory returned by `malloc` does not have to be used for a single object but may also be used for an array.

This means that the following are equivalent:

```
 int *p1 = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
 p1[0] = 1;
 p1[2] = 2;
 p1[3] = 3;
 ...
 int *p2 = calloc(3, sizeof(int));
 p2[0] = 1;
 p2[2] = 2;
 p2[3] = 3;
```

Both will return `3 * sizeof(int)` bytes of memory which can be used as an array of `int` of size 3.

Answer (score 0):

What malloc returns back to you is just a pointer to the starting memory address where the contiguous block of memory was allocated.

The size of the contiguous block of memory that you allocated using malloc depends on the argument you passed into malloc function. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

If you want to store `int` variable then you will do it by defining the pointer type you use to be of an `int` type.

example:

```
int p*; //pointer of type integer
size_t size = 20;
p = (int *) malloc(size); //returns to pointer p the memory address
```

after this, using the pointer p the programmer can access int (4 byte precision) values.

*calloc* only difference against *malloc* is that calloc initiallizes all values at this memory block to zero.